# Python - Type of variable gives different answer

Tags: python, python-2.7, types

I was reading a binary file, and here are two bytes which I represented in `byte1` and `byte2`
`byte` is a list

```
byte1 = byte[i]
byte2 = byte[i+1]
value1 = struct.unpack('B',byte1)[0], #this will be integer
value2 = struct.unpack('B',byte2)[0]
print type(value1) 
print type(value2)
```

But when I saw output, both value1 and value2 gave different types, instead should show same.

Output:

```
<type 'tuple'>
<type 'int'>
```

What am I missing?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a comma on the end of the line:

```
value1 = struct.unpack('B', byte1)[0], #this will be integer
#                                    ^
```

The comma makes the right hand side into a tuple.  Consider:

```
>>> a = 1,
>>> type(a)
<type 'tuple'>
>>> a = 'foo',
>>> type(a)
<type 'tuple'>
```

In each of these cases, the expression evaluates to a `tuple` due to the trailing comma.  The same is true for the code-snippet you've posted.

To get an integer, just remove the comma and all will be well:

```
value1 = struct.unpack('B', byte1)[0]
```

Comment: Oh my god! Python is amazing.

Comment: Thank you, I understood.